# Data was changed during edit it in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a multithreading app and I have a problem, I can open an item for make changes in a UIViewController but the data in another thread can be changed already, and when I click submit button - I rewrites the changes made by another thread. (for example the quantity of the item was changed - someone bought it while admin was changing the quantity of the items in the warehouse).

So now I have a UIViewController which can edit the item and make changes like this:

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender
{
        NSDictionary *changedData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameField.text, priceField.text, quantityField.text, _itemUUID, nil]
                                                                forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Price", @"Quantity", @"UUID", nil]];
        [[EADataManager sharedInstance] updateItemWithData:changedData atUUID:_itemUUID];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and the data update method in my dataManager class:

```
- (void) updateItemWithData:(NSDictionary *)data atUUID:(NSString*)UUID
{
    [self networkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    dispatch_barrier_async(_dataManagerQueue, ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
        NSInteger path = [self indexFromObjectUUID:UUID];
        if (path != NSNotFound)
        {
            [_items replaceObjectAtIndex:path withObject:data];
            [_dataStorageAdapter saveFileWithData:_items];
        } else {
            [_items addObject:data];
            [_dataStorageAdapter saveFileWithData:_items];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:EADataManagerUpdateViews
                                                                object:nil];
        });
        [self networkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    });
}
```

So the item can be edited from different threads or with other methods, and I don't know how to make this work well. I believe the delegation is quite good for this but I can't implement it here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize your model operations. That way you are safe from the unexpected results. You can read more at (Apple docs): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html.

Concerning the data changes that you are not aware of... Simply create an observable and an observer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), and notify everyone that data has changed. That way, when the background thread changes your data, your view controller will be notified and you can act accordingly.